# How to get all value of particular key in JSON?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I have a JSON structure that contains different levels. How to iterate the JSON and get all values of a particular key in JSON in C#

Below is my JSON file

```
{
"name": "EPM Company",
"id": "kpfwzgmhpm",
"type": "root",
"childern": [
    {
        "cid": "67",
        "cname": "cname1",
        "childern": [
            {
                "reading": [
                    {
                        "id": 121,
                        "name": "test1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 1121,
                        "name": "test11"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "cid": "454",
        "cname": "cname14",
        "childern": [
            {
                "reading": [
                    {
                        "id": 454,
                        "name": "test14"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 21,
                        "name": "test141"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is the JSON format. I am trying to get the value in the below format.

```
{
"name": "EPM Company",
"id": "kpfwzgmhpm",
"value": [
    {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "test1",
        "cid": "67",
        "cname": "cname1"
    },
    {
        "id": 1121,
        "name": "test11",
        "cid": "67",
        "cname": "cname1"
    },
    {
        "id": 124234,
        "cname": "test12342",
        "cid": "67",
        "name": "cname1"
    },
    {
        "id": 454,
        "name": "test14",
        "cid": "454",
        "cname": "cname14"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "name": "test141",
        "cid": "454",
        "cname": "cname14"
    },
     {
        "id": 121,
        "name": "test123122",
        "cid": "454",
        "cname": "cname14"
    }
]
```

}

fetching all the reading key and its value-added to array with its cid and came. is it possible?
advanced thanks for the help

my code in c# is

```
 public string SensorList(string entireData)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(entireData))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            var returnObj = new Jobject ();
            JObject o = JObject.Parse(entireData);
            var childern = o["children"];
            returnObj.Add("name" = o ["name"];
            returnObj.Add("id" = o ["id"];
            returnObj.Add("value" = o ["value"];
            var valuearry = new JArray();
            foreach(var data in childern)
            {
                 foreach(var reading in data["reading"])
            {

                var valobj = new Jobject ();
                valobj.Add( "cid",data["id"])
                valobj.Add( "cname",data["name"])
                valobj.Add( "name",reading["id"])
                valobj.Add( "id",reading["name"])

                valuearry.add()
                if(data.containsKey("children"))
                {
                    var sensorInfo = SensorList(data["children"]);
                }



            }
            returnObj.Add("value",valuearry);
            // var output = sensorInfo.SelectMany(x => ((JObject)x).Properties().Select(y => new JObject {
            //     new JProperty("id",y.Name),
            //   new JProperty("name",y.Value["name"])
            // })).ToList();
           // var returnArray = new JArray(output);

            return returnObj.ToString();
        }
    }
```

recurring part is not working and take too much time for other long JSON file

Comment: It seems like you haven't made any attempt to do this your self.

Comment: no. i did some coding. question its self is too lengthy that's whyI am not added that part

Comment: Well, we're not a free code-writing service here, but we will help you with code you've written. I strongly suggest you include your attempt (not the whole program, just enough code to sufficiently demonstrate your attempt) so that we can help you with it.

Comment: As it stands we don't even know what JSON serializer you're using.

Comment: The question "is it possible" is not suitable for StackOverflow in this context. I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To clarify: you want to change the format of the JSON while keeping all the same data. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. but I am fetching only particular key "reading " from all nodes

Comment: Is your example JSON correct? You seem to have two `name` properties in a single object.

Comment: corrected . one is cname and other is name

Comment: If your goal is to transform the JSON as quickly as possible, you'll have to go more low level and use the `JsonReader` and `JsonWriter` classes to stream the document instead of reading it into an object, working through it to create a new object, and then converting that back to a `string`. [Something like this as a starting point](https://rextester.com/YFYP39276). If you just want to prepare the JSON for reading in your own application, then a `JsonConverter` is a better option. Let me know more about what you want to do, and when this gets reopened I'll add an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your support. yes. incoming JSON is not dynamic and it has more low-level nodes

Comment: Something is weird in your sample output, I don't think the 3rd and 6th entries should be there.